# How can I make Spring converts camel case to snake case?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

With my Spring Boot 2.5.0 application, Spring does not convert my camel-cased entity/attribute names into snake-case table/columns.

I didn't set any `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.*` properties.

What are default values of those properties?

And what should I set for that?

```java
class MyEntity {                // I want it to be map from 'my_entity' table

    private String myAttribute; // I want it to be map from 'my_attribute' column
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You said that you didn't set any `naming` properties, but what about overriding of the default strategy in the configuration? according to the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-hibernate-naming-strategy) it should work as expected

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov You're right. I'm confused why the default strategy doesn't work. The problem was my multiple datasource configuration. I works not without any manullay configured strategies.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Hibernate's naming-strategy if you want to consistently apply these conventions...

```
class SnakeCaseNamingConvention implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        // apply snake-case conversion
        ...
    }

    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        // apply snake-case conversion
        ...
    }

    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are annotations to help you do just that:

```
@Table(name="my_entity")
class MyEntity {               
    @Column(name="my_attribute")
    private String myAttribute; 
}
```